# Why do protons not break into quarks?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, strong-force, confinement, proton-decay

1. I know that free a neutron breaks into a proton because a proton has less mass and energy. Then, why do protons not break into quarks, since they have even less energy?
2. Or why do gluons join quarks?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay

Comment: "
In the Standard Model, protons, a type of
baryon, are theoretically stable because
baryon number ( quark number) is
conserved (under normal circumstances;
however, see chiral anomaly ). Therefore,
protons will not decay into other particles
on their own, because they are the lightest
(and therefore least energetic) baryon."

It is unsatisfactory

Comment: unsatisfactory is that you had not read the link color confinement which was essentially the answer you accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say quarks "have even less energy," I assume you mean less mass-energy. While quarks individually have less mass-energy than a proton, three separated quarks have *more* energy than a proton. The quarks attract and bond to each other to reach a low energy state, and breaking that bond requires an energy input - which, ironically, supplies the necessary energy for a new set of quarks to form. So if you try to split a particle into a quark-antiquark pair by supplying energy, you just end up with two particles instead.